# Drawable with different appearence on android 2.3

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

I'm working with shapes and layer-lists. I have a LinearLayout with three TextView in line. I have created three drawable to draw a border around them like in the image, but on android 2.3 the central view top and bottom lines seem different from the other two.

[image: TextView with drawables]

Here is the code of the left drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/search_line_grey" android:width="1dp"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/home_images_corner_size"
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/home_images_corner_size"/>

</shape>
```

And here is the central one:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/search_line_grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp" android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I don't get which is the problem, if I set the bottom and top of central view to 2dp it became too tick, and this behaviour is only on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

@Marco,
as you are using `<corners>` in left and right views but not using it in central view, this problem is occurring

Comment: I've tried what are you suggesting but no luck until now. Can you explain it better?